# How to check if XML has same values in different nodes using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT and want your help

I have an XML with below format :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowset>
       <Row>
               <ActualHour>0.64</ActualHour>
       </Row>
       <Row>
               <ActualHour>0.64</ActualHour>
       </Row>
       <Row>
               <ActualHour>0.64</ActualHour>
       </Row>      
</Rowset>
```

I want to know how can I check whether "ActualHour" has same values across different "Row" node using XSLT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="/Rowset">
    <output>
       <xsl:value-of select="not(Row/ActualHour!=Row/ActualHour)"/>
    </output>    
</xsl:template>
```

The result in your example will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>true</output>
```

With an input like:

```
<Rowset>
       <Row>
               <ActualHour>0.64</ActualHour>
       </Row>
       <Row>
               <ActualHour>0.65</ActualHour>
       </Row>
       <Row>
               <ActualHour>0.64</ActualHour>
       </Row>      
</Rowset>
```

the result will be `false`.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm. If you don't mind, the .. is it used as a foreach here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: In your anser, you mentioned this line : "[ActualHour!=../Row/ActualHour]".
How exactly does it work? Like a for loop?

Comment: It works like a set comparison, because that's what it is. According to the [XPath specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans), *"the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-values of the two nodes is true."*

Comment: Thank you Michael :)